# sed: How can I print all matching in each line?

Tags: sed

I have a two-line string:

```
> a="Microarchitectural Data Sampling (MDS) aka CVE-2018-12126, CVE-2018-12127,CVE-2018-12130, CVE-2019-11091, publicly announced by Intel on 5/14/2019, this has high visibility and lots of public media exposure.\nMicroarchitectural Data Sampling (MDS) aka CVE-2018-12126, CVE-2018-12127,CVE-2018-12130, CVE-2019-11091, publicly announced by Intel on 5/14/2019, this has high visibility and lots of public media exposure."
> echo -e $a
Microarchitectural Data Sampling (MDS) aka CVE-2018-12126, CVE-2018-12127,CVE-2018-12130, CVE-2019-11091, publicly announced by Intel on 5/14/2019, this has high visibility and lots of public media exposure.
Microarchitectural Data Sampling (MDS) aka CVE-2018-12126, CVE-2018-12127,CVE-2018-12130, CVE-2019-11091, publicly announced by Intel on 5/14/2019, this has high visibility and lots of public media exposure.
```

What I want to print is:

```
CVE-2018-12126 CVE-2018-12127 CVE-2018-12130 CVE-2019-11091
CVE-2018-12126 CVE-2018-12127 CVE-2018-12130 CVE-2019-11091
# OR
CVE-2018-12126
CVE-2018-12127
CVE-2018-12130
CVE-2019-11091
CVE-2018-12126
CVE-2018-12127
CVE-2018-12130
CVE-2019-11091
```

I've tried below:

```
> echo -e $a | sed -r 's/.*(CVE-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4,6}).*/\1/g'
CVE-2019-11091
CVE-2019-11091
```

It only print the last matching of each line :-)

How to print all the matching groups?

Comment: Use [tag:grep] with `-o` flag, like `grep -oE 'CVE-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4,6}'`.

Comment: Thanks, the `grep -oE` works. BTW, is it possible by using sed to implement it?

Comment: Yes, but it wouldn't be as robust as grep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep` with `-o` option that will output matched substrings only:

```
grep -o 'CVE-[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{4,6\}' file > outputfile
```

Note the braces in `\{4\}` are escaped since this is the default POSIX BRE engine compliant regex.

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), the easy solution is to use two steps: wrap the expected matches with newlines and then extract those that exactly match your pattern:

```
pat='CVE-[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{4,6\}'
sed "s/$pat/\n&\n/g"  file.txt | sed -n "/^$pat\$/p" > outputfile
```

Output:

```
CVE-2018-12126
CVE-2018-12127
CVE-2018-12130
CVE-2019-11091
CVE-2018-12126
CVE-2018-12127
CVE-2018-12130
CVE-2019-11091
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/VooEou)

Comment: Thank you!
One comment, why you don't use `grep -E` or `sed -r`?
1. grep `-E, --extended-regexp`, _Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression_
2. sed `-r, --regexp-extended`, _use extended regular expressions in the script._

Comment: @piglot From what I read, `-r` is an older option, and `-E` is newer and works both on Linux and Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/\n/!s/CVE-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4,6}/\n&\n/g;/^CVE-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4,6}/P;D' file
```

Surround the required strings by newlines and then print those lines only.

Or if you prefer:

```
regexp='CVE-[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{4,6\}'
sed '/\n/!s/'$regexp'/\n&\n/g;/^'$regexp'/P;D' file
```